# How can I unlink a git repository in visual studio code

Tags: git, github

I was working in a project but I'm done now, I was handling git from vs code and now I want to remove the repository and don't know how to do it.

This is what I see in my vs code

[image]

I do not recognize any of those 10k changes, none of those files... I just want to make that number disappear. You see that "main" in the bottom left corner, that's the repository I want to remove.

I've read [How to unlink / sign out from Git repository in "Visual Studio Code" for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752341/how-to-unlink-sign-out-from-git-repository-in-visual-studio-code-for-mac) and [How to delete git repository(laravel project) on visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887655/how-to-delete-git-repositorylaravel-project-on-visual-studio-code)

I've tried deleting the .git folder, signed out of my github account from visual studio, uncheck the git : Github Authentification in the settings, pasting the `"git.enabled": false` into the settings.json, deleting the Personal Access Token in github(I didn't have one either).

None of what I mencioned above worked and don't know what else to try. I just want to remove the repository, not change it just unlink it. My last resource would be reinstall visual studio in hopes I get it but there should be one way to achieve this without doing something crazy.

Comment: "*I've tried deleting the .git folder…*" Which one?

Comment: the one that's created with `git init` and hides in my local project,

Comment: Well, I'd say you should delete all `.git` folders in project's the folder tree, but it seems you already did that... I can't imagine how git finds your local project if it does not have any `.git` folder in it...

Comment: @rottenCoderSo It seems you still have a directory `.git/` in your `$HOME`. Remove this one.

Comment: @phd I'm sorry but where do I find this `$HOME` ? you mean this one `C:\Users\campesino\.git` ?

Comment: @rottenCoderSo `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` https://stackoverflow.com/a/43313909/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/15193576/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init+home

Comment: @phd Today I came back to work on this issue and found out that its working good now. I guess me deleting the .git folder had something to do, if not then God knows what heppened here, now it shows the right number for every single repository once I open a different project. I still appreciate your time so thank you.